# Running a loop in separate time series in r

Tags: r

I have multiple time series and a single time series data runs from 1937 - 1943 and I want to run a loop in every single time series and I want an assistance in preparing the data properly. Any assistance is appreciated!

Data (I have around 30 multiple time series data and here under you get the first 3 time series data):

```
    Plot    Species Year    Count   Ppt Temp
e1q13   BG  1937    81  33.90833333 14.13181818
e1q13   BG  1938    45  48.18333333 15.14727273
e1q13   BG  1939    96  39.95833333 14.92
e1q13   BG  1940    44  48.36666667 14.27363636
e1q13   BG  1941    24  57.975  14.02
e1q13   BG  1942    8   59.55   13.65727273
e1q13   BG  1943    28  38.3    14.28363636
e1q13   BD  1937    135 33.90833333 14.13181818
e1q13   BD  1938    91  48.18333333 15.14727273
e1q13   BD  1939    171 39.95833333 14.92
e1q13   BD  1940    88  48.36666667 14.27363636
e1q13   BD  1941    59  57.975  14.02
e1q13   BD  1942    1   59.55   13.65727273
e1q13   BD  1943    1   38.3    14.28363636
e1q1a1  BG  1937    34  33.90833333 14.13181818
e1q1a1  BG  1938    16  48.18333333 15.14727273
e1q1a1  BG  1939    19  39.95833333 14.92
e1q1a1  BG  1940    35  48.36666667 14.27363636
e1q1a1  BG  1941    32  57.975  14.02
e1q1a1  BG  1942    7   59.55   13.65727273
e1q1a1  BG  1943    2   38.3    14.28363636
```

my code is:

```
 data$groups <- paste(data$Plot, data$Species, sep = "_")
data_by_plot <- split (data$Count, data$groups)
ly <- lapply(data_by_plot, function(df))
```

Comment: `data_by_plot` I guess has separate dataframes as you want, right? What is your question?

Comment: Yes, how can I make a loop that run in each time series separately if I use the first 6 as training set and the last one as testing set? I have more data and I want to know how it goes. I want my question short and precise to abide by stackoverflow rules., thanks @Ronak Shah

Comment: That is what you are already doing with `lapply` : `ly <- lapply(data_by_plot, function(df) {do something here})`. You can subset first 6 using indexing `training_set <- data_by_plot[1:6]`

Comment: so what am I going to put in the {do something here} position in case of loop?

Comment: You have not clarified in your question what you want to do for each time series. You can add the function that you want to apply on each of them.

Comment: @Ronak shah, then how to combine the final result from each unique combination?

Comment: How can I store the result in a single data frame or something as one from each unique plot-species combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` splits the dataframe into list of dataframes.

```
data_by_plot <- split(data$Count, data$groups)
```

Using `lapply` we can apply the same function to each dataframe.

```
ly <- lapply(data_by_plot, function(df){
  #Add code to be done on each dataframe in the list
})
```

To combine the data together into one dataframe again we can use

```
result <- do.call(rbind, ly)
```

Comment: To use the row of data_by_plot, can i use a syntax like , ly <- lapply(data_by_plot, function(df){
  n <- nrow(df) #and then the code that I want to be done
})

Comment: Yes you can use that. Also note that `nrow(df)` would give rows of each list and `nrow(data)` would give number of rows for the entire dataframe.

Comment: @Thanks Ronak, but it becomes hard for me to split the rows in the data_by_plot in to training set (row) of 9 and testing set of 6 (within that function), can you give me the hint? I know you have been helping too much

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean here. Probably better to ask a new question?